# mysql right join with where clause

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with this right Join, I have a table called live which hols properties for sale and I have an images table which contains the images for the properties.

I am trying to get all the images where the live.Status = 1

This works and returns results as expected ( without the live.status = 1 )

```
SELECT * 
FROM live
RIGHT JOIN images ON live.ID = images.imageId
WHERE images.ImgMoved =0
LIMIT 100
```

But When I try this I get a blank result set :

```
SELECT * 
FROM live
RIGHT JOIN images ON live.ID = images.imageId
WHERE images.ImgMoved = 0 AND live.Status = 1
LIMIT 100
```

What am I doing wrong

thanks

Comment: Why are you using `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: I dont know !!! I will try it now

Comment: That won't fix the problem.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: INNER JOIN DOE STHE SAME Barmar

Comment: Perhaps you do not have any records that satisfy the where criteria. The issue is with the data, not with the syntax, so without sample data this question cannot be answered.

Comment: @BarryConnolly I know it does. If you understand the difference between INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN, you should know that it can never return more rows. INNER JOIN only returns matching rows, OUTER JOIN can also returns rows in one of the tables that doesn't have a match in the other.

Comment: That's why I said it won't fix the problem. I was just wondering why you were using `RIGHT JOIN` if you only want rows with `live.Status = 1`.

Comment: Are you going to post the data and expected results? If not, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I find LEFT JOINs much more intuitive, and the following easier to read...

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM images x 
  LEFT
JOIN live y
  ON y.ID = x.imageId
 AND y.Status = 1
 WHERE x.ImgMoved = 0
 ORDER
    BY x.id
 LIMIT 100
```